# Use the formal definition of limit

Tags: calculus

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 1} (x^2+1)=2$$

How do I do this?

I know this:

$$|x^2-1|<\epsilon$$

$$0<|x-1|<δ$$

But how do I continue from that?

Comment: Here's a MathJax tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You want to prove that for any $\epsilon>0$ you can find a specific choice of $\delta>0$ that makes the implication $|x-1|<\delta\implies |x^2-1|<\epsilon$ true.  The choice of $\delta$ will generally depend on the value of $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

$$ |(x^2+1) - 2| = |x^2-1| = |x-1|.|x+1|$$

If we set $\delta = \min(\epsilon, 1)$.

Then, $$|x-1|  < \delta \Rightarrow 0 < x < 2 \Rightarrow 1 < x+1 < 3 \Rightarrow |x+1| < 3$$

but also:

$$ | x-1| < \delta \Rightarrow |x-1||x+1| < 3|x-1| < 3\epsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

Given $f(x)=x^2+1$, to prove that

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \, \left(x^2+1\right)=2$$

we need to show that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that IF $|x-1|<\delta $ then $\left|(x^2+1)-2\right|<\varepsilon$ that is $\left|x^2-1\right|<\varepsilon$ which means $-\varepsilon <x^2-1<\varepsilon$ or, assuming $\varepsilon < 1$ we must have $1-\varepsilon<x^2<1+\varepsilon$ whose solution is $\sqrt{1-\varepsilon}<x<\sqrt{1+\varepsilon}$.

Therefore if $\sqrt{1-\varepsilon}-1<x-1<\sqrt{1+\varepsilon}-1$ and then if we take $\delta=\sqrt{1+\varepsilon}-1$ we are sure that if $|x-1|<\delta$ then $\left|f(x)-2\right|<\varepsilon$

For instance, suppose $\varepsilon = \dfrac{1}{1000}$

we take $\delta=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{1000}}-1\approx 0.0005$ we have that if $|x-1|<0.0005$ let's say $x=1.0003$, then $|f(x)-2|<\frac{1}{10000}$

Indeed $(1.0003^2+1)-2\approx 0.0006 < \frac{1}{10000}$

Hope this can be useful